# How to check the key value is exist in a JSON object using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I need one help. I have some json value and i need to check if the `key` is exist or not using Angular.js. I am explaining my code below.

```
var data=[{
    'checked':true,
    'name':'aaa'
},{
   'checked':true,
   'name':'bbb'
},{
   'name':'vvv'
}
]
```

Here i need fetch  those value which have `checked and checked==true` only. Please help me.

Comment: `data.filter(i => i.checked)` in ES6 syntax… Either way: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 1):

```
var checkedData = data.filter((item) => {
  return item.checked;
});
```

Comment: This is such a good case for the compact `item => item.checked` syntax…!

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter for this, from which you can filter by particular key. 
In your controller :

```
$scope.data=[{
    'checked':true,
    'name':'aaa'
},{
   'checked':true,
   'name':'bbb'
},{
   'name':'vvv'
}
]
```

In your view :

```
{{data | filter:{'checked': 'true'} }}
```

Answer (score 0):

General search function (in case if you don't need other values. Otherwise - use filter instead).

```
var check = function (data) {
    var checkResult = [];
    angular.forEach(data, function(item) {
        if (item.checked === true) {
            checkResult.push(item);
        }
    });
    return checkResult;
}
```

Usage

```
check(data);
```

Filter (if you want to render checked items only)

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{checked:true}"></div>
```